# Rename multiple files using cmd

Tags: for-loop, cmd, file-rename

I'm trying to rename multiple files in a folder using CMD prompt. Following code renames as `file1`, `file2`,... but I want to append from a middle value like `file51`, `file52`,...

```
SET /a "#="
FOR %_ IN (*) DO (
  CALL SET /A "#=#+1"
  CALL REN "%~f_" "file%#%.jpg" )
```

If I use `SET /a "#=51"` in first line, it is getting executed for every loop, initializing the value to `51` every time.
What am I missing out?

Comment: The part `%#%` should read `%^#%` (assuming that there is no variable named `^#`). Then the first `call` is not necessary, and you should either remove `/a` from your first line or put the value `0` to avoid `Missing operand.` errors.

Comment: Like this? SET "#="
FOR %_ IN (*) DO (
  SET "#=#+1"
  CALL REN "%~f_" "file%^#%.jpg" )  This renames only the first file as file%^#%.jpg. For other files "A duplicate filename exists" error is thrown.

Comment: Uhm… no, you missed the `/A` in your second `set` command, where it is mandatory…